# Auto scroll horizontally while adding columns to a ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, scrollbar, autoscroll

I want to auto scroll the ListView horizontally to the last column every time a ColumnHeader is added.
I need only to scroll to the last Column, not to the item.

- `listView1.Alignment` is set to Left
- `listView1.View` is set to `View.Details`

I tried this, but it doesn't do anything:

```
listView1.AutoScrollOffset = new Point(listView1.AutoScrollOffset.X-10, 0);`
```

This only works if I add only items:

```
listView1.EnsureVisible(0);
```

---

```
string rowstr = "Test,";
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(i);
    
    ColumnHeader head = new ColumnHeader();
    head.Text = i.toString();
    listView1.Columns.Add(head);
    listView1.Columns[i].Width = 65;
    
    rowstr += "Test"+",";
    string[] row = rowstr.Split(",");
    var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
    listViewItem.Font = new Font("Consolas", 10f);
    listView1.Items.Insert(0, listViewItem);

    //listView1.EnsureVisible(0);
    listView1.AutoScrollOffset = new Point(listView1.AutoScrollOffset.X-10, 0); 
}
```

I didn't try to override WndProc or to call a User32 function, but if this is the only option any help is appreciated.
If it's possibile without PInvoking, that would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scroll horizontally a ListView, you can send a [LVM_SCROLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-scroll) message to the Control, setting `wParam` to a value that correspond to position (in pixels) to scroll to.
The position is relative to the current offset.
Set `lParam` to scroll vertically.

Since you want to scroll to the last Column and the ListView is in `Details` mode, you can just pass `int.MaxValue` as the offset: the Win32 Control will do the adjustment (it does it anyway).

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, int lParam);

private const int LVM_SCROLL = 0x1014;
SendMessage(listView1.Handle, LVM_SCROLL, int.MaxValue, 0);
```

**EDIT:**
Modify your code, adding an interval between the each Column/ListItem insertion, to see it in slow motion. You can use a `Button.Click` handler.

```
private async void SomeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++) {
        var head = new ColumnHeader() {
            Text = idx.ToString(),
            Width = 65
        };
        listView1.Columns.Add(head);
        SendMessage(listView1.Handle, LVM_SCROLL, int.MaxValue, 0);
        var rowArray = new List<string>(Enumerable.Range(0, idx + 1).Select(n => $"Test{n}"));
        var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(rowArray.ToArray());
        listView1.Items.Insert(0, listViewItem);
        SendMessage(listView1.Handle, LVM_SCROLL, int.MaxValue, 0);
        await Task.Delay(500);
    }
}
```

Remove the `async` stuff to let it go free.

---

To get the current scroll position, if needed, use [GetScrollInfo()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getscrollinfo). E.g.,

```
var scrollInfo = new SCROLLINFO(SBInfoMask.SIF_ALL);
bool result = GetScrollInfo(listView1.Handle, SBParam.SB_HORZ, ref scrollInfo);
```

The `nPos` member of the [SCROLLINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-scrollinfo) struct returns the current scroll position. `nMax` the maximum scroll value. Subtract `nPage`, corresponding to the Control's `ClientSize.Width`, to get the maximum possible scroll value.
It should be equal to `nPos` when the thumb is scrolled to the end.

Win32 declarations:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool GetScrollInfo(IntPtr hwnd, SBParam nBar, [In, Out] ref Point lpsi);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct SCROLLINFO
{
    public uint cbSize;
    public SBInfoMask fMask;
    public int nMin;
    public int nMax;
    public uint nPage;
    public int nPos;
    public int nTrackPos;

    public SCROLLINFO(SBInfoMask mask)
    {
        cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf<SCROLLINFO>();
        fMask = mask;
        nMin = 0; nMax = 0; nPage = 0; nPos = 0; nTrackPos = 0;
    }
}

internal enum SBInfoMask : uint
{
    SIF_RANGE = 0x1,
    SIF_PAGE = 0x2,
    SIF_POS = 0x4,
    SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL = 0x8,
    SIF_TRACKPOS = 0x10,
    SIF_ALL = (SIF_RANGE | SIF_PAGE | SIF_POS | SIF_TRACKPOS),
    SIF_POSRANGE = (SIF_RANGE | SIF_POS | SIF_PAGE)
}

public enum SBParam : int
{
    SB_HORZ = 0x0,
    SB_VERT = 0x1,
    SB_CTL = 0x2,
    SB_BOTH = 0x3
}
```

Comment: My solution was also user32 SendMessage. 
`private const int WM_HSCROLL = 0x114; private const int WPARAM = 7; SendMessage(listView1.Handle, WM_HSCROLL, WPARAM, 0);`
I used  0x114 for horizontal scroll and 7 as Wparam and it worked, below 7 didnt scroll to the end.

Comment: I tried your solution and the scrollbar jumps to the last column but after jumps always back to the beginning while adding columns.

Comment: I don't know how you implemented it. See the edit for an example.

Comment: I added `SendMessage` after column add and item add and like that it **works.**

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `CustomListView` and `Re_Define` the **`EnsureVisible`** method

```
class DataFlowFilterListView : ListView
{
    /// <summary>
    /// margin from the selected column to the border of listview.
    /// </summary>
    const int MARGIN = 20;

    /// <summary>
    /// native windows message to scroll the listview.
    /// </summary>
    const Int32 LVM_FIRST = 0x1000;
    const Int32 LVM_SCROLL = LVM_FIRST + 20;

    [DllImport("user32")]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr Handle, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
    IntPtr lParam);

    private void ScrollHorizontal(int pixelsToScroll)
    {
       SendMessage(this.Handle, LVM_SCROLL, (IntPtr)pixelsToScroll,
       IntPtr.Zero);
    }

     /// <summary>
     /// Ensure visible of a ListViewItem and SubItem Index.
     /// 
     /// 
     /// </summary>
     /// <param name="item"></param>
     /// <param name="subItemIndex"></param>
     public void EnsureVisible(ListViewItem item, int subItemIndex)
     {
         if (item == null || subItemIndex > item.SubItems.Count - 1)
         {
           throw new ArgumentException();
         }

         // scroll to the item row.
         item.EnsureVisible();
         ScrollToRectangle(item.SubItems[subItemIndex].Bounds.Width);
     }

     /// <summary>
     /// Scrolls the listview.
     /// </summary>
     /// <param name="bounds"></param>
     private void ScrollToRectangle(int width)
     {
         this.ScrollHorizontal(width);
     }
}
```

*Now you can use `DataFlowFilterListView` instead of `ListView`.*

---

***Execute the following code each time you add a column to the list***

```
listView1.EnsureVisible(listView1.Items[0], 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is using user32 function and `SendMessage()`.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

private const int WM_HSCROLL = 0x114; //for horizontal scroll
private const int WPARAM = 7; //to scroll to end
```

Implementation:

```
string rowstr = "Code,"
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    ColumnHeader head = new ColumnHeader();
    head.Text = i.toString();
    listView1.Columns.Add(head);
    listView1.Columns[i].Width = 65;
    
    rowstr += "Test"+",";
    string[] row = rowstr.Split(",");
    var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
    listViewItem.Font = new Font("Consolas", 10f);
    listView1.Items.Insert(0, listViewItem);
    SendMessage(listView1.Handle, WM_HSCROLL, WPARAM, 0);
}
```